# How to disable cookies and cache in Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, caching, cookies

I am facing a problem regarding the cache and cookies and Codeigniter.

When I log in using a username and a password, there is a prompt like this.

[image: Save Password]

I then click `Save Password`. After that I have one form where there are also username and password fields. These fields become automatically filled with the username and password that I have entered from the previous application login.

[image: One Form]

How do I get rid of the username and password? I am using Codeigniter.

Comment: I think its the behaviour of browser not cache or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/SZxksnnm4dc) that presents a theory. I quote:

> If the browser detects <input type="password">, it will assume that the <input type="text"> IMMEDIATELY in front of it is the username input.

With some testing myself, I found this to be true.

[image: theory test]

In searching for solutions I found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15917221/2431281).

Specifically:

> Simply create a couple of fields and make them hidden with "display:none". Example:

```
<!-- fake fields are a workaround for chrome autofill getting the wrong fields -->
<input style="display:none" type="text" name="fakeusernameremembered"/>
<input style="display:none" type="password" name="fakepasswordremembered"/>
```

This is a **kludgy solution**. However it works.

[image: kludgy soln]