# Programmatically disabling Chrome auto-fill

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

There’s some discussion about this around the internet (especially here on stack overflow), but quite a lot of it dates from around 2015, so I was wondering if anyone had any recent experience.

We use a JavaScript widget to power type-ahead search functionality on web forms, but this UI is consistently overlaid with the Chrome autofill.

While `autocomplete=“off”` used to work, Chrome seems to ignore this value now, and show the UI anyway. The only thing I can find that works with Chrome 66/67 on OSX is an invalid value, such as `autocomplete=“blah”`. This seems way too sketchy though, and we have experimented with this before and it gets ignored in certain situations/Chrome versions.

Has anyone fond a reliable way to turn this off using HTML/Javascript?

As a side note - it looks like even Google can’t turn it off when needed, as their own Google maps type-ahead widget gets overlaid by the Chrome autofill. This can be seen on most Shopify stores.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50405068/disable-autocomplete-in-chrome-66/50571447#50571447

Comment: Never had any trouble with it, but if all else fails you can go with a `div[contenteditable]` ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**jquery.disable-autofill**

Disable Chrome's autofill. Handy for CRUD forms, when you don't want username/password inputs to be autofilled by the browser.

> Usage:

```
<form>
  <input type="input" name="username" autofill="off" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="password" name="password"  autofill="off" autocomplete="off">
</form>

<script src="jquery.disable-autofill.js"></script>
<script>
  $('input[autofill="off"]').disableAutofill();
</script>
```

https://github.com/biesbjerg/jquery.disable-autofill

Comment: Your answer `$('input[autofill="off"]).disableAutofill();` is missing a single quote.

Comment: Lol, jquery is the selected answer?

Answer (score 26):

`autocomplete="off"` **doesn't work** anymore. The only thing which works as of **2019** is `autocomplete="new-password"`

Check this link on Chromium Project
https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/form-styles-that-chromium-understands

> Add an autocomplete attribute with a value of username for usernames.
>
> If you've implemented an "email first" sign-in flow that separates the
>   username and password into two separate forms, include a form field
>   containing the username in the form used to collect the password. You
>   can, of course, hide this field via CSS if that's appropriate for your
>   layout.
>
> Add an autocomplete attribute with a value of current-password
>   for the password field on a sign-in form.
>
> Add an autocomplete
>   attribute with a value of new-password for the password field on
>   sign-up and change-password forms.
>
> If you require the user to type
>   their password twice during sign-up or password update, add the
>   new-password autocomplete attribute on both fields.

```html
<form id="login" action="signup.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" autocomplete="new-password">
  <input type="password" autocomplete="new-password">
  <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
</form>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It seems Chrome seems to keep changing the way they hide this type of field

Comment: It seems just the password input needs it.

Answer (score 13):

You can just put `autocomplete="new-password"` in your password field and that's it.
That should work just fine!

Comment: Works a lot better than the jquery code above and a lot less code

Comment: @DavidCyr You can use 1 line of jQuery for the same effect. `$('input').attr("autocomplete", "new-password");`

Comment: Note: This does not work in FF yet(also see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#The_autocomplete_attribute_and_login_fields)). @User He had nothing against jQuery itself, but against the `disableAutofill` Plugin.

Comment: not working in Chrome 2019.  It turns off Chrome mulit-field autocomplete and enables single field autocomplete.

Comment: Nov 2019.  Chome 78.0.3904.97 (Official Build) (64-bit).  Works just fine for me.

Comment: Wow! thanks - this worked miraculously and it deserves the best answer tick.

Answer (score 6):

I solved this problem using **autocomplete="nope"**

```html
<input type="text" autocomplete="nope" />
```

Comment: This worked for me as well, I prefer this over "new-password", for non-password fields!

Comment: This worked for me thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For React, you could do something like this -

```
<input id={id} name={'a'+Math.random()} type="text" />
```

if all you need to do is access the input value elsewhere by the id, eg

```
const value = document.getElementById(id)
```

(This is partly how the jQuery Disable Auto Fill Plugin works).

Comment: I've used this but put the random string at the end of the autocomplete value. Works every time, running for over a year now.

Answer (score 1):

At this time (May, 2019) only `autocomplete="new-password"` is working well.

It can do programmatically with jQuery for example :

```
$('form, input, select').attr('autocomplete', 'new-password');
```

Answer (score 1):

Work to me

```
  <input [name]="nameControl" type="text" autocomplete="new-password">
```

in the component:

```
  this.nameControl = "name" + this.getRandomInt();

  getRandomInt() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(100));
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @Rinat! Please try and only add answers that haven't been listed above. This same answer is listed above multiple times. Just a kind heads up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery in September, 2019. The only thing close to consistency I've achieved for disabling autocomplete/autofill on an entire form:

```
$('.disable-autofill').focus(function () {
    $(this).attr('autocomplete', 'new-password');
});
$('.disable-autofill').blur(function () {
    $(this).removeAttr('autocomplete');
});
```

Then apply class to your inputs e.g.:

```
<input name="first_name" class="disable-autofill">
```

You have to remove the attribute because if too many inputs have `autocomplete` then chrome starts ignoring it again :)

Answer (score 1):

I could solve it with this code:

```html
<form autocomplete="off">
 <input type="text" name="text" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="off" autocorrect="off"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a very elegant sollution but it works. The autofill fires on document ready. If we disable the input fields for a second it fail and then we can re-enable the input forms.
This can be usefull for login forms and user forms on cruds.
A better approach will be to set some overlay with a loading animation or something more user friendly.

Jquery example:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#[FORM_ID] input').prop('disabled',true);
   setTimeout(function(){ $('#[FORM_ID] input').prop('disabled',false); }, 1000);
});
```

Replace #[FORM_ID] with the id of your form.

Answer (score 0):

**OLD ANSWER:**

You can try brute force:

```
function annihilateChromesAutocomplete(){
    var clearAutocompleteInterval = setInterval(function(){
        var peskyAutocompletedInputs = document.querySelectorAll("input:-internal-autofill-selected");
        for(var i = (peskyAutocompletedInputs.length - 1); i > -1; i--){
            peskyAutocompletedInputs[i].value = peskyAutocompletedInputs[i].defaultValue;
        }
    }, 1);
    setTimeout(function(){
        clearInterval(clearAutocompleteInterval);
    }, 2000);
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I've stumbled upon a simpler, cleaner solution to this. If you make the default `type` of the input something weird like `time` and then change the `type` dynamically with JavaScript when the page loads, Chrome will look for the nth `time` input and end up ignoring your inputs.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
    if(inputs[i].type == "time"){
      inputs[i].type = "text";
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="time"/>
<input type="time"/>
<input type="time"/>
```

Of course, you can change specific inputs to whatever types you want. I'm just throwing out an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to save password in browser, here is a solution using just css.
Select type="text" for input field:

```
<input class="text-security-disc" type="text">
```

and add style to input, which hides text:

```
.text-security-disc {
    -webkit-text-security: disc;
    -moz-text-security: disc;
    text-security: disc;
}
```

This doesn't work for Mozilla Firefox, I've used this font:
https://github.com/noppa/text-security

Answer (score 0):

**How to disable Autofill in Chrome 86+**

*I tried several methods but non of them worked so I came up with workaround below. If there will be an update from Chrome Dev-team on proper Autofill disabling mechanism, this answer will not be relevant and should not be used.*

1. Add .disable-autocomplete class to any input field(s).

```
<input name="blahblah" type="text" class="disable-autocomplete">
```

2. Turn off address autocomplete by giving unique Autocomplete value and Regular Autofill by giving unique ID.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script>
var uniqueAutocompleteID = + new Date();
$(".disable-autocomplete").attr("autocomplete", uniqueAutocompleteID);
$(".disable-autocomplete").attr("id", uniqueAutocompleteID);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try https://github.com/terrylinooo/disableautofill.js

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/disableautofill@2.0.0/dist/disableautofill.min.js"></script>
```

Usage:

```js
 var daf = new disableautofill({
    'form': '#testForm',
    'fields': [
        '.test-pass',  // password
        '.test-pass2'  // confirm password
    ],
    'debug': true,
    'callback': function() {
        return checkForm(); // Form validator
    }
});

daf.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  `autocomplete="off"` to disable `autocomplete`

and `type="search"` to disable address `autofill`

Comment: What if the type="tel"?

Answer (score -2):

make sure your input elem is inside a `<form>` tag. disabling auto-fill did not worked for me until that.

Comment: The asker wants to disable chrome auto-fill. Your link shows how to enable it.

Comment: @Lytigas, disabling auto-filling didn't worked for me by any method until put inside a <form> tag. sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. In the future, this would make a great comment on some of the other answers. Generally, an answer should provide a fully-formed solution.