# How to turn off text box suggestions in Google Chrome using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I was tried to prevent to store the username and password in Google Chrome password manager. so, I was changed the type password to text in the password field using following lines in jQuery in `$(document).ready` section.

```
     var isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);
    if (isChrome) {
        $("#UserPassword").attr("type", 'text');
        $("#UserPassword").attr("style", "-webkit-text-security:disc;");
    }
    else {
        $("#UserPassword").attr("type", 'password');
    }
```

but, I faced, some issue due to the address fill suggestion. it shows the already typed values in the suggestion. how to prevent show the suggestion in field or how prevent Google Chrome password manager to save the password from my site.

[image]

**Enable Suggestion in Google Chrome:**

1. Open settings page in Google Chrome
2. Select Autofill and password in left panel
3. Then select the Addresses and more in Right Panel and enable the Save and fill addresses option.

Any one knows please give me suggestion for solve this issue

Comment: You can add autocomplete attribute and set it as `off`, Find relevant solution 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50604671/programmatically-disabling-chrome-auto-fill#:~:text=jquery.disable%2Dautofill,be%20autofilled%20by%20the%20browser.&text=Your%20answer%20%24('input%5Bautofill,is%20missing%20a%20single%20quote.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you disable browser autocomplete on web form field / input tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am asked about autofill in field. i required for avoid show suggestion in that fields.

Now, i got one solution for avoid this scenario.

In the Suggestion show based on the field name.

```
function formsubmit(e){
    e.preventdefault();
    $("#userpassword").attr("name","Password"");
    $("#loginform").submit();
}


 <form action="/account/login" id="loginform" >
    <input type="text" name="123123124343_Password" id="userpassword"></input>
    <input type="submit" onclick="formsubmit()" value="Login"></input>
   </form>
```

so,i was set the dynamic name for the field with unique id. in form submit event, i changed the field name as i required.

Now, the suggestion box is not appeared in that field

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript, you can disable text box suggestions in Google Chrome by using the autocomplete attribute of the input element.

```
var inputElement = document.getElementById("myInput");
inputElement.setAttribute("autocomplete", "off");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added the html attribute: autocomplete="one-time-code" to input type=text html elements or asp:TextBox in Asp.Net in order to fix this problem. I don't know where I where I first found this, but it works. This should work in Html5 browsers. It works in Google Chrome.